# Getting Value From Nested Table FormArray In Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

I had a trouble finding the amount based from quantity * price. The problem is because each row has sub rows How will i able to get the amount from the quantity and the price? Here's my code below.

Here is also the link to my demo code [PLEASE CLICK THIS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-nested-array-ab5dqp?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
getAmount(value: FormControl) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['people'];
    this.total = 0;
    control.controls.forEach((field) => {
      field.get('addresses')['controls'].forEach(element => {
        const col1 = +field.get('price')
        const col2 = +element.get('quantity');
        const sum = col1 * col2;

        // Get Amount
        element.get('amount').patchValue(sum, { emitEvent: false });

        // Get Grand Total
        this.total += sum;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: who downvoted? This is a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to cast FormControl to number while you need to get value from control and then cast to number:

So instead of:

```
const col1 = +field.get('price')
const col2 = +element.get('quantity');
```

you should be doing something like:

```
const col1 = +(field.get('price').value || 0);
const col2 = +(element.get('quantity').value || 0);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-nested-array-7i3u6y?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: why there is || 0?

Comment: In case if value of your controls is `undefined`

Comment: Thanks. can i do it too when instantiating the form. In this quantity[0, Validators.required]. Is this the same thing?

Comment: If you're sure that the value will never be `undefined` then you can omit it.

Comment: Hi yurzui. Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026735/custom-validator-control-quantity-in-reactive-forms. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

If you want to calculate amount based from `quantity * price`

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-nested-array-eytkzf)

```
<td>
{{ myForm['controls'].people.controls[i].controls.addresses.controls[j].controls.amount.value }}
</td>

 getAmount(value) {
    value.forEach((pdata, i) => {
      pdata.addresses.forEach((data, k) => {
        this.myForm['controls'].people['controls'][i].controls.addresses.controls[k].controls.amount.patchValue((pdata.price * data.quantity), { emitEvent: false });
      })
    });
```

Comment: I'll upvote this but i don't want to load the template with functions. I want functions to be implemented by ts file.

Comment: but i am not calling any function from template. have u seen?? it is just formGroup controls.

Comment: You are multiplying the quantity and the price in the template. I just want it to be done in the ts file

Comment: You can just finish my getAmount function in my ts file. Thanks

Comment: you have to do multiply in template because. you need to capture change in both price and quantity.

Comment: You can do it in the ts file too.

Comment: Can you check demo now??

Comment: You're nearing now. But i want it to be using ValueChanges. Just finish my function and don't change anything in the template. Sorry for that and thank you

Comment: I will try my best wait.

Comment: Working Fine Check solution.

Comment: By the way check time of edit. but its ok hope u git right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry. I'll post again another question after 5 hours.  Thanks for your time

Comment: ha ha ha :):) nice

Comment: Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026735/custom-validator-control-quantity-in-reactive-forms

Comment: Hows my new question?