# Custom Validator Control Quantity in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I had a hard time implementing a custom validation in my reactive forms in Angular. I need to control the quantity. The quantity should not be more than the available quantity. The problem how can i get the total of all the quantity if each row has subrows. How will i able to compute the total of subrows and compare it to its parent row where the available quantity is found. Here's my code below.

Here's also the link to my code [PLEASE CLICK THIS LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-nested-array-ab5dqp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
customValidator(campo1: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
      const receive = group.controls[campo1];
       //Change this
      const available = 10;
      if (receive.value > available) {
        return {
          out: true
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key is using "parent" to reach the formArray. then we can use map to transform the array and get only que quantity and reduce to get the sum of the quantities

```
customValidator(campo1: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
      //get the formArray
      const form=(group.parent as FormArray);
      if (form)
      {
        //get the available quantity using parent
        let available =form.parent.get('available_quantity').value;

        //the final available are the available less each quantity
        available=form.value //In form.value we have e.g. [{quantity:10..},{quantity:16}]
          .map(x=>x.quantity?+x.quantity:0)  //using map we have, e.g. [10,16]
          .reduce((a, b) => a - b, available)  //using reduce we substract the quantities to available
        if (available<0) {
          return {
            out: true
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you lessen your code? I don't maybe need this const receive = group.controls[campo1];  etc...

Comment: How about these "{ [key: string]: any }" and "campo1: string in customerValidator()"? Do i need to put this? Thank you.

Comment: True, it's not necesary in this case, i let it in case it was necesary to check the value (imagine if you want to check if the value is negative). The {key:string...} is the type of the "return" of the function. All the comment are "only propouse" the code was intelligible

Comment: Can you remove all unecessary code? Thank you eliseo

Comment: How about the campo:string in the customValidator() ? Do i need that? I dont need that parameters?