# How to check duplicate formcontrol values exist in form arrays in reactive forms in angular5?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-forms

I am building form array like

```
    this.myForm= this.fb.group({
  codes: this.fb.array([])
 })

 this.codes =   this.myForm.controls['newChargecodes']

  this.codes.push(this.fb.group({
     chargeCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
  })


  addRow () {
   this.codes.push(this.fb.group({
     chargeCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
  })

  }

  Html

  <tr *ngFor="let code of myForm.get('codes').controls; let i = index;" 
              [formGroupName]="i">
               <td class="text-center">
                  <input class="form-control input-text text-center" pInputText type="text" placeholder="{{columns['chargeCode']}}" id="chargeCode"
                    formControlName="chargeCode" name="chargeCode">
                </td>
                <td>< a (click)="addRow()">+</a></td>
 </tr>
```

I want duplicate code validation

example like if user enter

```
chargecode[0]-A1, -> true
 chargecode[1]-A2, -> true
 chargecode[2]-A1-> -> false->
```

it shoulD show error duplicate charge code while user enter input

Please help me how to write custom validation for form arrays in reactive forms

Comment: see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026735/custom-validator-control-quantity-in-reactive-forms/52035863#52035863 how "reach" the formArray of a form

Answer (score 2):

Check that working solution as :

> Validating Duplicate Person name here in example.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfvt5a)

TS:

```
findDuplicate(name, p): boolean {
   let myArray = this.getPeople(this.myForm);

   let test = myArray.filter(data => data.controls.name.value == name && name != null)

   if (test.length > 1) {
      return true;
   } else {
     return false
 }}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-group" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <table class="table" formArrayName="people">
        <thead class="thead bg-info">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">People Name
                    <button (click)="addPeople()" type="button">+</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let person of getPeople(myForm); let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
                    <p style="color:red;" *ngIf="!findDuplicate(person, i) && i > 0">Duplicate Name </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be inspired by this idea to solve a similar problem. Article:
[Custom Group Validation in Angular 2](https://eyalvardi.wordpress.com/2016/08/28/custom-group-validation-in-angular-2/)

There is live example [live example](http://embed.plnkr.co/bOxBqf5iz3WjYZtce7Ky/)

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you want to compare two input value in this form. in this case, I have the password and confirmPassword form controls:

```
  createForm(): void {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      password: ['', [Validators.required]],
      passwordConfirm: ['', [Validators.required, this.passwordConfirmValidator]]
    });
  }
```

And the passwordConfirmValidator is a function like this:

```
  passwordConfirmValidator(input: FormControl) {
    const value = input.value;
    if (value === input.root.value.password) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return 'Not Equal';
    }
  }
```

As you see, you can access the other form controles by root property.

Comment: This is not what he asked brother!